# How to make a similar interface using wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How to make a similar interface using wxWidgets [image: form] ?
I need to dynamically create text fields. I know how to do this with Delphi [gitHub](https://github.com/Nindzzya/Delphi.git). But how to do it with C++ and wxWidgets?

here is my code. I do not understand what to do

```
Simple::Simple(const wxString& title)
: wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(270, 450))
{
    wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            hbox->Add(new wxListBox(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250, 60)), wxSizerFlags(0).Border(wxALL, 5));
            auto itm = hbox->GetItem(i);
            itm->SetId(i);
        }
    SetSizer(hbox);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nindzzya,

Basically you create a wxFrame. You put an instance of wxScrolled<> in it. Then inside this wxScrolled<>() you put a vertical wxBoxSizer. And then finally add the appropriate controls inside that sizer.

Following your example:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        textctrl[i] = new wxTextCtrl( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize( 250, 60 ), wxSizerFlags( 0 ).Border( wxALL, 5 ) )
        hbox->Add( textctrl[i] );
    }

MyFrame::Some_Func()
{
    for( auto i : { 0, 25 } )
    {
        textctrl[i]->GetValue();
    }
}
```

You don't even need an id or anything like this. And this question is about basic C++. It doesn't have anything to do with wxWidgets.

Comment: I dont understand how to do it.

Comment: You will need to spend some time thinking about it and reading/researching about it. In the post you asked a very broad question without showing what you'd tried so far. Then your only response to this answer is something unactionable. Help us to help you.

Comment: @Nindzzya, look at the scrolled sample provided by wxWidgets. Look at the documentation, Then try to modify the sample so it will do what you want. Also, re-read my reply - you need wxScrolled<>() on the frame.

Comment: @Igor, how to access wxTextCtrl which is created in a loop?

Comment: @Nindzzya, you can assign an id to the control - this is the easiest. or if you need it inside some event handler - look at the `event.GetEventObject()` method.

Comment: @Igor, I set ID. how to connect to this object via ID?

Comment: @Nindzzya, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to know what text control user was typing in?

Comment: @Igor, I want to set/get a text. not user input

Comment: @Nindzzya, answer updated. No need for anything special. Just create a static array as a member of the frame and use the code in my post. Pretty straightforward - and the second question itself is about C++.

Comment: @Igor, yeap i know. i little stupid. But, c++ hobby for me,not work